# Consulta SQL-Datos Repetidos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas!
Tengo dos tablas(`VOIPCLIENTE`, `VOIPMAQUINA`) donde en `VOIPCLIENTE` tengo información sobre los clientes(`CLIENTE,DELEGACIÓN...`) y en `VOIMPAQUINA` sobre las máquinas(`MAQUINA,EMPRESA...`) .

Estas dos tablas tienen mas campos pero únicamente las relaciona un campo, `CLIENTE=EMPRESA`.

Cuando yo hago mi consulta sql, relacionando esos dos campos y consultando la `MAQUINA` me salen máquinas repetidas.

La consulta:

```
SELECT maquina.MAQUINADELEG,clientes.CLIENTE,maquina.EMPRESA,maquina.MAQUINA
FROM dbo.VOIPCLIENTE clientes, dbo.VOIPMAQUINA maquina
WHERE maquina.EMPRESA = clientes.CLIENTE order by maquina
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver, salen siempre 3 filas repetidas.

Comment: ¿Cuales son las claves primarias de ambas tablas?

Comment: CLIENTEDELEG y MAQUINADELEG. No tienen relación alguna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la clave primaria de clientes es `CLIENTEDELEG`  se ve incorrecto que referencies via  `clientes.CLIENTE` . Deberias verificar que la referencia 
`maquina.EMPRESA` realmente (es decir, según diseño, y según restricción de Foreign Key, si se está usando) apunta a  `clientes.CLIENTE` y, de paso,  verificar que `clientes.CLIENTE` es, si no una clave primaria, al menos una clave secundaria o un campo con restricción de unicidad.

Una consulta rápida para investigar :

`SELECT * from cliente where CLIENTE = 100004`

Si eso tira varios resultados, entonces estamos en problemas o bien de diseño o bien de interpretación del diseño (de paso: un diseño que usa el mismo nombre para la tabla y una columna de esa tabla... [no huele bien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475798/foo-foo-is-giving-a-table-column-the-same-name-as-the-table-itself-a-bad-idea))

Comment: Solucionado. Gracias, tu respuesta me ha hecho pensar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un SELECT DISTINCT con la Maquina y luego un JOIN con el resto de elementos.
[SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Prueba simplemente así:
`SELECT DISTINCT maquina.MAQUINADELEG,clientes.CLIENTE,maquina.EMPRESA,maquina.MAQUINA
FROM dbo.VOIPCLIENTE clientes, dbo.VOIPMAQUINA maquina
WHERE maquina.EMPRESA = clientes.CLIENTE order by maquina`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te recomendaría ampliar un poco tu respuesta. Piensa que estas respuestas sirven de guía para muchas personas por lo que interesa que las respuestas sean completas. Seguro que eres capaz de aportar un ejemplo por tonto que sea para complementar la respuesta. Además, las respuestas basadas en enlaces son peligrosas. Tu respuesta no servirá para nada si el enlace deja de estar disponible en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

dos cosas deberias primero si quieres relacionar usar un inner join y ahi poner la relacion maquina.EMPRESA = clientes.CLIENTE, teniendo en cuenta que esa es la relacion lo cual dudo es decir

```
SELECT maquina.MAQUINADELEG,clientes.CLIENTE,maquina.EMPRESA,maquina.MAQUINA
FROM dbo.VOIPCLIENTE clientes
INNER JOIN dbo.VOIPMAQUINA maquina ON maquina.EMPRESA = clientes.CLIENTE 
ORDER by maquina asc
```

segundo si solo quieres usar tu query y no siendo lo mas eficiente usa un distinct para eliminar valores repetidos

```
SELECT maquina.MAQUINADELEG,clientes.CLIENTE,maquina.EMPRESA,maquina.MAQUINA
FROM dbo.VOIPCLIENTE clientes, dbo.VOIPMAQUINA maquina
WHERE maquina.EMPRESA = clientes.CLIENTE order by maquina
```